# stripe customer portal link won't open in iframe

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, iframe, strip

```
const cust_portal = https://billing.stripe.com/p/session/test_YWNjdF8xTkNuYmRIeW9HS21GdWpMLF9PMXpTb3NwUsdfdsjNFRmRGc5dThZd3hHU2VmdWpZ0100NmxjzxnT
```

```
<iframe src={cust_portal}></iframe>
```

The result is a link refused to connect error:

```
Refused to frame 'https://billing.stripe.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".
```

The link works if I open in a new tab like so:

```
window.open(cust_portal)
```